# Cygwin binutils configure Cached Incorrectly

Tags: linux, cygwin, configure, binutils

I'm trying to install binutils in a Cygwin environment.

My path was very screwed up (e.g. one line of configure's output was:

```
"checking for ld... (cached) c:/dev/perl/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe"
```

, which is clearly nasty), so I altered Cygwin's /etc/profile to that the path was much simpler.

However, when running configure, it reports that some values (like the above) are "(cached)".  I thought this might be related to invalid state in a config.cache file, but after removing all such files from the computer the problem persists.

What does a cached value mean, and how can I get it updated?

Answer (score 0):

*make distclean* should give you a pristine build environment for you to start from scratch with.

Comment: Running "make distclean" in "/cygdrive/c/dev/cygwin/usr/src/binutils-2.23.1" produces the following: http://pastebin.com/Lp2W1Rmw and the problem persists.

Comment: Are you having build problems or asking for a solution in search of a problem?

Comment: Yeah, build problem is http://pastebin.com/EQtiTS3h, see 752.  Someone on forum.osdev.org thought it was the PATH variables.